# Domain to S3 Bucket AccessDenied

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns-zone, dns-hosting

Hello i have a problem i recibe AccessDenied in my domain

I upload my site in to a AWS S3 Bucket, i make public, create a static page, but when i access via my domain.com/mypage i get a AccessDenied.

From the aws mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/mypage works fine.

My domain DNS are setup like this

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com. 2101 IN CNAME mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com.
mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com. 41342 IN CNAME s3-1-w.amazonaws.com.
s3-1-w.amazonaws.com.   219 IN  CNAME   s3-w.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
s3-w.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 3 IN  A   52.217.69.36
```

Any advice to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is [from the Amazon support documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/):

> **Short description**:
>
> To troubleshoot Access Denied errors, determine if your distribution’s
> origin domain name is an S3 website endpoint or an S3 REST API
> endpoint. Follow these steps to determine the endpoint type:
>
> 1. Open the CloudFront console.
> 2. Choose your CloudFront distribution, and then choose Distribution Settings.
> 3. Choose the Origins and Origin Groups tab.
> 4. Choose the Origins and Origin Groups tab.
>
> Review the domain name under Origin Domain Name and Path, and then
> determine the endpoint type based on the format of the domain name.
>
> **REST API endpoints use this format:**
>
> ```
> DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com
> ```
>
> **Note**: Make sure to follow the rules for naming Amazon S3 buckets.
>
> Website endpoints use this format:
>
> ```
> DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
> ```
>
> **Note**: Depending on the AWS Region, the endpoint format might use the dash format (s3-website-Region) or the dot format
> (s3-website.Region).
>
> If your distribution is using a REST API endpoint, see I'm using an S3
> REST API endpoint as the origin of my CloudFront distribution. **Why
> am I getting 403 Access Denied errors?**
>
> If your distribution is using a website endpoint, verify the following
> requirements to avoid Access Denied errors:
>
> 1. Objects in the bucket must be publicly accessible.
> 2. Objects in the bucket can't be encrypted by AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS).
> 3. The bucket policy must allow access to s3:GetObject.
> 4. If the bucket policy grants public read access, then the AWS account that owns the bucket must also own the object.
>    5.The requested objects must exist in the bucket.
> 5. Amazon S3 Block Public Access must be disabled on the bucket.
> 6. If Requester Pays is enabled, then the request must include the request-payer parameter.
> 7. If you're using a Referer header to restrict access from CloudFront to your S3 origin, then review the custom header.
>
> **Note**: If you don't want to allow public (**anonymous**) access to your S3 objects, then change your configuration to use the S3 REST API
> endpoint as the origin of your distribution. Then, configure your
> distribution and S3 bucket to restrict access using an origin access
> identity (OAI). For instructions, see Using a REST API endpoint as the
> origin with access restricted by an OAI in How do I use CloudFront to
> serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3?
>
> **Resolution**
>
> **Objects in the bucket must be publicly accessible**
>
> A distribution using a website endpoint supports only publicly
> accessible content. To determine if an object in your S3 bucket is
> publicly accessible, open the object's URL in a web browser. Or, you
> can run a curl command on the URL.
>
> The following is an example URL of an S3 object:
>
> ```
> http://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html
> ```
>
> If the web browser or curl command returns an Access Denied error,
> then the object isn't publicly accessible.
>
> Allow public read access to the object in one of the following ways:
>
> 1. Create a bucket policy that allows public read access for all objects in the bucket.
> 2. Use the Amazon S3 console to allow public read access for the object.
> 3. Objects in the bucket can't be AWS KMS-encrypted
> 4. CloudFront distributions don't support AWS KMS-encrypted objects. You must remove KMS encryption from the S3 objects that you want to
>    serve using the distribution.
>
> **Note**: Instead of using AWS KMS encryption, use AES-256 to encrypt your objects.
>
> Use one of the following ways to check if an object in your bucket is
> KMS-encrypted:
>
> Use the Amazon S3 console to view the properties of the object. Review
> the Encryption dialog box. If AWS-KMS is selected, then the object is
> KMS-encrypted. Run the head-object command using the AWS Command Line
> Interface (AWS CLI). If the command returns ServerSideEncryption as
> aws:kms, then the object is KMS-encrypted. Note: If you receive errors
> when running AWS CLI commands, make sure that you’re using the most
> recent version of the AWS CLI. To change the object's encryption
> settings using the Amazon S3 console, see How do I add encryption to
> an S3 object?
>
> To change the object's encryption settings using the **AWS CLI**,
> first verify that the object's bucket doesn't have default encryption.
> If the bucket doesn't have default encryption, then run the following
> command to remove the object's encryption by copying the object over
> itself:
>
> ```
> aws s3 cp s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/index.html s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/index.html
> ```
>
> **Warning**: Copying the object over itself removes settings for storage-class and
> website-redirect-location. To maintain these settings in the new
> object, be sure to explicitly specify storage-class or
> website-redirect-location values in the copy request.
>
> The bucket policy must allow access to s3:GetObject To use a
> distribution with an S3 website endpoint, your bucket policy must not
> have a deny statement that blocks public read access to the
> s3:GetObject action.
>
> Even if you have an explicit allow statement for s3:GetObject in your
> bucket policy, confirm that there isn't a conflicting explicit deny
> statement. An explicit deny statement always overrides an explicit
> allow statement.
>
> Follow these steps to review your bucket policy for s3:GetObject:
>
> 1. Open your S3 bucket from the Amazon S3 console.
> 2. Choose the Permissions tab.
> 3. Choose Bucket Policy.
> 4. Review the bucket policy for statements with "Action": "s3:GetObject" or "Action": "s3:*".
>
> The following example policy contains an explicit allow statement for
> public access to s3:GetObject. However, there's also an explicit deny
> statement for s3:GetObject that blocks access unless the request is
> from a specific Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC).
>
> ```
> {
>     "Version": "2008-10-17",
>     "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Sid": "Allow-OAI-Access-To-Bucket",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Principal": {
>                 "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EAF5XXXXXXXXX"
>             },
>             "Action": "s3:GetObject",
>             "Resource": [
>                 "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "Sid": "Allow-Public-Access-To-Bucket",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Principal": "*",
>             "Action": "s3:GetObject",
>             "Resource": [
>                 "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
>             "Effect": "Deny",
>             "Principal": "*",
>             "Action": "s3:GetObject",
>             "Resource": [
>                 "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
>             ],
>             "Condition": {
>                 "StringNotEquals": {
>                     "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1a2b3c4d"
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     ]
>   }
> ```
>
> 5. Modify the bucket policy to remove or edit statements that block public read access to s3:GetObject.
>
> **Note**: CloudFront caches the results of an Access Denied error for the amount of time specified in the error caching minimum TTL. The
> default value is one minute. After removing a deny statement from the
> bucket policy, you can run an invalidation on your distribution to
> remove the object from the cache.
>
> If the bucket policy grants public read access, then the AWS account
> that owns the bucket must also own the object For a bucket policy to
> allow public read access to objects, the AWS account that owns the
> bucket must also own the objects. A bucket or object is owned by the
> account of the AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) identity that
> created the bucket or object.
>
> **Note**: The object-ownership requirement applies to public read access granted by a bucket policy. It doesn't apply to public read
> access granted by the object's access control list (ACL).
>
> Follow these steps to check if the bucket and objects have the same
> owner:
>
> 1. Run this AWS CLI command to get the S3 canonical ID of the bucket owner:
>
> ```
> aws s3api list-buckets --query Owner.ID
> ```
>
> 2. Run this command to get the S3 canonical ID of the object owner:
>
> Note: This example shows a single object, but you can use the list
> command to check several objects.
>
> ```
> aws s3api list-objects --bucket DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET --prefix index.html
> ```
>
> 3. If the canonical IDs don't match, then the bucket and object have different owners.
>
> Note: You can also use the Amazon S3 console to check the bucket and
> object owners. The owners are found in the Permissions tab of the
> respective bucket or object.
>
> Follow these steps to change the object's owner to the bucket owner:
>
> 1. From the object owner's account, run this command to retrieve the ACL permissions assigned to the object:
>
> ```
> aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET --key object-name
> ```
>
> 2. If the object has bucket-owner-full-control ACL permissions, then skip to step #3. If the object doesn't have
>    bucket-owner-full-control ACL permissions, then run this command from
>    the object owner's account:
>
> ```
> aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET --key object-name --acl bucket-owner-full-control
> ```
>
> 3. From the bucket owner's account, run this command to change the owner of the object by copying the object over itself:
>
> ```
> aws s3 cp s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/index.html s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/index.html
> ```
>
> **The requested objects must exist in the bucket** If a user doesn’t have s3:ListBucket permissions, then the user gets Access Denied
> errors for missing objects instead of 404 Not Found errors. Run the
> head-object AWS CLI command to check if an object exists in the
> bucket.
>
> **Note**: Confirm that the object request sent to CloudFront matches the S3 object name exactly. S3 object names are case-sensitive. If the
> request doesn't have the correct object name, then Amazon S3 responds
> as though the object is missing. To identify which object CloudFront
> is requesting from Amazon S3, use server access logging.
>
> If the object exists in the bucket, then the Access Denied error isn't
> **masking a 404 Not Found error**. Verify other configuration requirements to resolve the Access Denied error.
>
> If the object isn’t in the bucket, then the Access Denied error is
> **masking a 404 Not Found error**. Resolve the issue related to the missing object.
>
> **Note**: It's not a security best practice to enable public s3:ListBucket access. Enabling public s3:ListBucket access allows
> users to see and list all objects in a bucket. This exposes object
> metadata details (for example, key and size) to users even if the
> users don't have permissions for downloading the object.
>
> **Amazon S3 Block Public Access must be disabled on the bucket** Confirm that there aren't any Amazon S3 Block Public Access settings
> applied to the bucket. These settings can override permissions that
> allow public read access. Amazon S3 Block Public Access settings can
> apply to individual buckets or AWS accounts.
>
> If Requester Pays is enabled, then the request must include the
> request-payer parameter If Requester Pays is enabled on a bucket, then
> anonymous access to the bucket is not allowed. Users from other
> accounts must specify the request-payer parameter when they send
> requests to the bucket. Otherwise, those users get an Access Denied
> error.
>
> If you're using a Referer header to restrict access from CloudFront to
> your S3 origin, then review the custom header If you're using the
> Referer header to restrict access from CloudFront to your S3 website
> endpoint origin, check the secret value or token set on the S3 bucket
> policy. Then, confirm that the secret value or token matches the value
> on the CloudFront origin custom header.
>
> If you're using an explicit deny statement in the bucket policy, then
> confirm that there's also an allow statement that grants access based
> on the Referer header. You can't grant access with only an explicit
> deny statement.
>
> **For example**, the following bucket policy grants access to the S3 origin when the request contains the string
> **"aws:Referer":"MY_SECRET_TOKEN_CONFIGURED_ON_CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_CUSTOM_HEADER":**
>
> ```
> {
>   "Version":"2012-10-17",
>   "Id":"http referer policy example",
>   "Statement":[
>     {
>       "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from my CloudFront with referer header",
>       "Effect":"Allow",
>       "Principal":"*",
>       "Action":"s3:GetObject",
>       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*",
>       "Condition":{
>         "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":"MY_SECRET_TOKEN_CONFIGURED_ON_CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_CUSTOM_HEADER"}
>       }
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> With this example bucket policy, the CloudFront origin custom header
> must be:
>
> - **Header**: Referer
> - **Value:** MY_SECRET_TOKEN_CONFIGURED_ON_CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_CUSTOM_HEADER
>
> **Note:**
> The example bucket policy grants public (anonymous) access to the
> bucket because the Principal is a wildcard value ("Principal":"*").
> However, because of the condition statement, access to the S3 origin
> is granted only if the request includes the Referer header and the
> header value matches the value in the bucket policy.